# Every group element is a product of elements in certain subsets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group. For $\theta \in$ Aut$(G)$ of order $2$, define
$$ K:=\{ g\in G \mid \theta(g)=g \},\quad S:=\{ \theta(g)^{-1}g \mid g\in G \}.$$

My first question is:

> Assume there is a bijection $f:S \to S$ defined by $f(x)=x^2$, prove that for 
>   $g\in G$ there exist uniquely $k\in K$ and $s\in S$ such that $g=ks$.

**EDITED:**
As noted in comments, I was careless not adding a very important assumption that order of $\theta$ is $2$. I made this condition added and understood why if $x\in S$ then $x^2\in S$ even before the first question were asked. I know that if there exist $k\in K$ and $s\in S$ such that $g=ks$, then they are determined uniquely. It is because for $k'\in K$ and $s'\in S$ such that $g=k's'$, we have $s=k^{-1}k's'$. Since $\theta(s)=s^{-1}$ for all $s \in S$,
$s^{-1}=\theta(s)=k^{-1}k's'^{-1}$. It follows that, $s^{-1}s'=k^{-1}k'=ss'^{-1}$ i.e. 
$s^2=s'^{2}$. By the bijectivity of $f$ we must have $s=s'$ hence $k=k'$.

How about proving the existence of $k$ and $s$?

My second question is:

> Give an example of $(G, \theta , K, S)$ such that the bijection $f$ described above exists.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As for your first question, you assume that $f$ is a bijection, so that if $x \in S$, then $\exists ! y \in S$ with $y = x^2$.

Comment: @walkar don't you mean that for every $y\in S$, there is a unique $x\in S$ such that $y = x^2$?

Comment: @kobe Ah, yes. I'll leave it as is, with your comment.

Comment: For the first question, it is the assumption that if $x\in S$ then $x^2\in S$. Then for any $g\in G$ $\theta(g)^{-1}g\theta(g)^{-1}g\in S$ in particular, there exists $h_g\in G$ such that $\theta(g)^{-1}g\theta(g)^{-1}g=\theta(h_g)^{-1}h_g$.

Comment: I actually mean is it true that if $x \in S$ then $x^2 \in S$ before the first question were asked?

Comment: @user it's not necessarily true, but it's assumed in the first question.

Comment: I'm really sorry I missed a very important assumption in the beginning. The order of $\theta$ is $2$. I edited.

Comment: Now I understand why $x \in S \implies x^2 \in S$. It is because if $x=\theta(g)^{-1}g$ for some $g \in G$ then $x\theta(x)=1.$ Hence $x^2=\theta(x)^{-1}x \in S$.

Comment: @user yes, that's correct.

Comment: I still got stuck in finding $k$ and $s$ in the first question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove existence in the first question, let $g\in G$ and consider the product $\theta(g)^{-1}g$: since it is an element of $S$ and $f$ is onto, there exists an $s\in S$ such that $\theta(g)^{-1}g = s^2$. Let $k = \theta(g)s$. Then $g = ks$, so it suffices to show $\theta(k) = k$: $$\theta(k) = \theta(\theta(g))\theta(s) = g\theta(s) = gs^{-1} = k$$

To answer the second question, consider the automorphism $\theta :(\mathbb{Z}_3,+) \xrightarrow{2} (\mathbb{Z}_3,+)$. For this automorphism, $K = 0$ and $S = \mathbb{Z}_3$. The map $f : \Bbb Z_3 \to \Bbb Z_3$ is the same as $\theta$, so it is a bijection.

Comment: It seems one place needs a correction. The equality $g=ks$ isn't true for your choice of $k$ and $s$. It should be $\theta(g)^{-1}g=s^2$ by the surjectivity of $f$.

Comment: Thanks @user, I've made the correction.

Comment: It's now perfect :)